# Tired of AC power adapters

Tags: power-supply

I have about 20 to 30 peripherals on my computers. Each one with its own &%$/&#$% AC power adapter. I really hate these power adapters.

I am thinking of there's some kind of power supply I can buy (similar to those used in electronics) that comes with different voltages (typically +5 -5 +12 -12 +9 -9 and can even supply HP printers +36V if I am not wrong) and I can use to power all peripherals at once. One power supply with wires and plugs to all devices would be a wonderful solution.

Is there something I can buy or adapt to do this?

Comment: 20 or 30 peripherals? Holy crap.

Comment: 3 computers and a lot of stuff, including a bunch of USB hubs each one with its own (/$(/&#$$ power adapter :(

Comment: OMG, 20-30 peripherals ....hmm GOD Bless You

Comment: @subanki - ... each one with its own power ?!

Comment: 90% of them. Imagine all those creatures reproducing on my floor... I hate them.

Answer (score 2):

I wish someone would invent some sort of universal DC standard so we could get rid of all those adapters.

Comment: The new [Universal Charging Solution](http://gsmworld.com/our-work/mobile_planet/green_power_for_mobile/product_overview.htm) adopted by the mobile phone industry is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend universal adapters, there are some good ones but they are usually more expensive and then you will be wasting a perfectly good one you already have.

Personally, I would suggest you find a good method of organising your current adapters.

I wrap the cord in circles and use reversible/undo-able cable ties, and put stickers on the plugs that say what they are for. This makes them easy to identify and easy to manage without a lot of waste cable.

Comment: +1 for properly organizing cables. If you start at home, you'll have a head start if you have to organize a data center ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are "universal" power supplies, with various connectors and switchable output voltage.

One example:

http://www.conrad.de/ce/de/product/420296/Universal-Netzteil-NP100-EC-f-Notebooks

You should be able to get them at any well-stocked electronics supplier.

They are, however, generally more expensive than regular power supplies. Also, you must take care never to set a voltage that is too high for the connected device; otherwise you might fry it.

Also, some devices (e.g. laptops) may need a "smart" power supply, that contains special charging circuitry. These would not work with such a universal power supply. That said, all the laptops I know just have a regular power supply, so that may not be an issue.

Note that even a switchable power supply can only supply one voltage at a time. I don't think there are power supplies with multiple, independent outputs (as they would effectively be two supplies in one box).

Comment: the problem with this is that you can only supply one peripheral at a time. I need a box that I can attached zillions of wires and attach all peripherals, so I get rid of thousands of parasitic AC adapters attached to chords and outlets.